# Syncing code Compute Engine with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

My project use Django, and I need run the Django's ORM in Compute Engine, for this I want sync in one repository both Compute Engine and App Engine with my development server.

When I try:

```
gcloud init <proyect>
```

From the Compute Engine, the log is:

```
ERROR: Unable to initialize project [tcontur2], cleaning up [***].
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Your git version 1.7.10 is older than the minimum version 1.8.1.
Please install a newer version of git.
```

I try

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

And nothing.

I too try:

```
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/myproyect
```

But the authenication fails. What is the username and password? It is not my gmail user account.

Is possible sync the Compute Engine with the code in App Engine? or only is possible with another repository? This option suppose other payment to Github, I dont want spend more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue from my fresh Debian instance and I was able to solve it. I downloaded the new git version from: http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/detail?name=git-1.9.0.tar.gz

Also I needed to install some packages that you may have already installed but just in case I'll let you know which are them.

These are the steps I've taken:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev gettext
wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.9.0.tar.gz   
tar -xvzf git-1.9.0.tar.gz
cd git-1.9.0
sudo make prefix=/usr all
sudo make prefix=/usr install
```

After that you can check your git version with:

```
git --version
```

Now, if the output of the last command displays "git version 1.9.0", you should be able to create the repository with the command:

```
gclod init <project>
```